# NHibernate Domain Model - Adding Child Objects to Collections

Tags: nhibernate, contains

I'm still learning here and have a question about child collections. I have an aggregate root called Audio, which has a collection of AudioDownloads.

The downloads are records of each IP address which downloads the audio, i don't want to have duplicate records of the same IP for each Audio.

In my domain i have the following function:

```
 public virtual void Add(AudioDownload download)
    {
        if (!AudioDownloads.Contains(download)) {
            TotalDownloads++;
            AudioDownloads.Add(download);
        }
    }
```

And this is how i am calling the Add function:

```
var download = new AudioDownload();
audio.Add(download);
```

This is returning all downloads from the database for this Audio (which chould be thousands!), also it's still adding the download even though one already exists.

I'm using S#arp with the DomainSignature approach for comparing my entities.

Here is my Domain:

```
public class AudioDownload : Entity, ITenantSpecific
{
    public AudioDownload() { DateAdded = DateTime.Now; }

    [DomainSignature]
    public virtual Audio Audio { get; set; }

    [DomainSignature]
    public virtual string Ip { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

My question is...even if i can get AudioDownloads not to add duplicate entries, should i be doing it this way at all?

Thank you very much!

Paul

Comment: Why are you doing a manual Contains() check whether the element is already contained, instead of using an ISet for the collection (which would do this automatically)?

Comment: Hi,

I have tried setting it to ISet but it's still letting me add a duplicate entry.

My entity has 3 properties.

-Id
-Audio
-DateTime

Would the DateTime property make each Download unique or should it ignore this if i am not using the [DomainSignature] filter on that property?

Paul

Comment: I think you'll need to override equals on AudioDownload class

Comment: I beleive the DomainSignature filters perform this action for you already which are part of the s#arp framework. I beleive they override the equals and hashcode.

I have resorted to simply checking to see if the item exists in the database inside my service layer before i make the call to AudioDownloads.Add() method on my domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that most ways to do this will always lead you to query all downloads from the database, which is probably not what you want.

Another approach that might be cheaper is just to have a unique key in the database defined based on AudioId and Ip. If you then insert a record that duplicates these you will get an exception from NHibernate telling you a unique key was violated: handle that exception gracefully (i.e. don't show it as an error, load the existing AudioDownload and use that in future) and you will have achieved your goal, I believe.

When you use this approach do not check whether the download is already contained in the collection, since that would still trigger loading of all records.

On the other hand: would it not be interesting to see that something was downloaded from the same Ip multiple times?

Comment: The reason i want to do this is to keep a total of how many unique downloads each Audio has had. Could there be an alternative approach to this situation.

I also have a seperate entity called AudioDownloadsByUser which instead of logging the IP, it will log the users Id if logged in.

They both inherit from AudioHit.

AudioHit
 - AudioDownloadByIp
 - AudioDownloadByUser

I'm going to investigate ISet & your approach, will post back my findings.

Thanks guys!
Paul

Comment: If you want unique downloads per IP you could also write a 'distinct' query to count that number.
On a side note: IPs are not really guaranteed to be used by the same person all the time. Some internet providers don't give their users the same IP at various points in time, so the value of the result might not be that high (your approach with logged in user is more reliable)...

Comment: I realised that and i know it's not going to be 100%, unfortunately i need to also keep a count from the none-logged in members also.

I am using a mixture of Sessions, Cookies & IP address to try and narrow it down as much as possible.

Thanks for the heads up though!